# The book one receives upon graduation to cherish the times spent at school

Tags: word-choice

The word candidates I can come up with are:

1. Scrapbook. A conglomeration of photos and short texts that aren't necessarily related to one another.
2. Album. Same as photo book.
3. Memento book. Different from *memento mori*, it is life not death that should be conveyed to the reader, who then needs to answer the question "Are you now living your life as fully as you have had during your school years?"
4. Memoirs. Same as autobiographies.

---

Edit: While yearbook comes close to what I am looking for, the book should be a highlight of the things done by a student throughout **ALL** his/her years at the school. Maybe "yearsbook"? But as @vidget suggested, there is no such word in the dictionary, so I'll accept yearbook.

Comment: Is this something you've or your friends compiled on your own? Is it a one-of-a-kind thing or something that was compiled, edited and published through an official or semi-official capacity of the school?

Comment: It's meant to be a semi-official gift to the students by the school, and thus more personalized than a "publication" like a school magazine/journal.

Comment: That sounds really cool, and indeed more specialized than a yearbook. A yearbook generally takes a broad perspective, covering the activities of the entire school for a single year. Since you're really describing something that focuses on a single student's entire time at the school, a different term is in order. *Yearsbook* is a reasonable extension, but doesn't sound quite right to me. Btw, *memento* can also mean *an object kept as a reminder or souvenir of a person or event,* and sounds less formal to me in that context. I'll post an answer if I can think of anything new.

Comment: I don't know if a book covering one's whole high school experience is a very common thing. As a native US-English speaker I've not heard a word for this exact thing. As you suggest, one could use a generic word like 'memento' and even compound it to say "high school memento." But you'll not find that in a dictionary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We always just called them *yearbooks.* But these were the same ones we could purchase at the end of every school year, so not sure if that's different from something particular to graduation.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qLkyj8YJDf4

Sure, it's a "yearbook".  Certainly in USA-English, where the concept is most popular.